# How to convert pending intent to byte[]

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I am developing notification listener application. Here I receive all notifications.But how to convert pending intent to byte[] and vice versa from notification.

```
   @Override public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) { 
     System.out.println("Notification_AGS: onNotificationPosted");
     if (SharedPreferenceManager.getPrefStoragePermission(context)) { 
       notificationList.clear();
       String packageName = sbn.getPackageName(); 
       PendingIntent pendingIntent = sbn.getNotification().contentIntent
     }
   }
```

Comment: could you please post your code

Comment: you should not try to `convert pending intent to byte[]`.It won't work. Whay you want to do that?

Comment: Actually I am storing notification in sqlite. I want to save notification action also. So that I am trying to convert it to byte[]

Comment: why do you want to use pendingintent if you want to store in db, you can actually do it here itself

Comment: Main purpose is to see all old notifications with its actions.Thousands of logs I am storing in local. if I store its action then we can retrieve right ?

Comment: then better create a model class with only data you want to store, and store those objects.

Comment: Correct. But we can't store pending intent directly in sqlite right ? But we can able to store byte[]. So that I try to convert pending intent to byte[]

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize a `PendingIntent` to a `Parcel` and then convert the `Parcel` into a byte array like this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = ...
Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
pendingIntent.pendingIntent.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);
byte[] bytes = parcel.marshall();
```

Beware of the following:

> The documentation explicitly states that the resulting byte array
>   should NOT be stored in a persistent storage because the byte array is
>   a highly optimized serialized form and it is not guaranteed that the
>   `Parcel` can be successfully recreated from the byte array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While trying this I got run time exception.

Comment: Edit your question and post your new code and runtime exception with stack trace in your question.